# What method is best for accomplishing this Parsing task?(Python)

Tags: python, csv, parsing, csvreader

I have a small parsing project I need to complete for work.

With some suggestion I can complete this just need some ideas and ideas how to best clean this up.

My task is to take a csv file(makes.csv) with lines like
FYI I put those headers.

Input:

```
yearStart, yearEnd, make, model
2016, 2020, lamborghini, Aventador
2016, 2020, Chevrolet, Malibu
2016, 2019, Chevrolet, Cruze
2014, 2018, Mazda, 3
2016, 2018, Mazda, CX3
2012, 2018, Mazda, CX5
2014, 2014, Mazda, SPEED3
2013, 2018, Hyundai, Santa Fe
2015, 2015, Hyundai, Genesis
2013, 2014, Cadillac, ATS
2013, 2015, Cadillac, XTS

I need to parse this file to get data back in the format below

Chevrolet
  Camaro (16-20)
  Malibu (16-20)

Cadillac
  ATS    (12-14)
  XTS    (13-15)
Hyundai etc etc
```

Essentially every Make needs to be parsed with the models printed below with their respective year start and end date.

I need a jog of memory or pseudo code to figure out how to do this logically.

Currently I have

```
import csv

with open('makes.csv','r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, skipinitialspace=True)

    with open('newoutput.csv', 'w') as new_file:
        fieldnames = ['yearStart','yearEnd','make','model']

        csv_writer=csv.DictWriter(new_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, extrasaction='ignore',delimiter='\t')

        csv_writer.writeheader()
        count = 0
        
        for line in csv_reader:
            count += 1
            del line['yearStart']
            del line['yearEnd']
            del line['model']
            csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

Using the csv file above I can get the below output

OUTPUT:

```
yearStart   yearEnd make    model

        lamborghini 

        Chevrolet   

        Chevrolet   

        Mazda   

        Mazda   

        Mazda   

        Mazda   

        Hyundai 

        Hyundai 

        Cadillac    

        Cadillac    

        Jeep    

        Lincoln 

        Lincoln 

        Kia
```

So the question is what is the best way to compare the strings to only print a make once and then provide the makes below it.

Do I need to implement a data structure to compare strings or does a loop that counts how many times a certain string has been seen and then stops printing that Make.

Some thoughts:
I looked through some REGEX documents and tutorials.
Would that be helpful at all here?

Data structure to compare string needed and if yes what do you recommend?

What else am I missing?

EDIT:
I was able to implement the solution below and tried to write to CSV file using append.
However, my solution is overwriting the rows.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

with open('newoutput.csv', 'w') as new_file:
    df= pd.read_csv('makes.csv')
    d=[]
    p=[]
    for k,g in df.groupby('make'):
        d.append([k])
        for _,r in g.iterrows():
            p.append([f'  {r["model"]} ({r["yearStart"]-2000:02d}-{r["yearEnd"]-2000:02d})'])
    
    df1=pd.DataFrame(d)
    df2=pd.DataFrame(p)
    df1.to_csv('newoutput.csv')
    df2.to_csv('newoutput.csv')
```

OUTPUT

```
,0
0,   ATS (13-14)
1,   XTS (13-15)
2,   Malibu (16-20)
3,   Cruze (16-19)
4,   Santa Fe (13-18)
5,   Genesis (15-15)
6,   Cherokee (14-21)
7,   Amanti (03-06)
8,   MKS (09-12)
9,   MKT (10-12)
10,   3 (14-18)
11,   CX3 (16-18)
12,   CX5 (12-18)
13,   SPEED3 (14-14)
14,   aventador (16-20)
```

If I remove the code seen below to send the date to csv I get

```
    df1=pd.DataFrame(d)
    #df2=pd.DataFrame(p)
    df1.to_csv('newoutput.csv')
    #df2.to_csv('newoutput.csv')

OUTPUT 

,0
0, Cadillac
1, Chevrolet
2, Hyundai
3, Jeep
4, Kia
5, Lincoln
6, Mazda
7, lamborghini
```

Is there a better way to send that data to CSV?
Why is it overwriting the date?

Answer (score 2):

Read you file with [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), then iterate the groups, then rows.

Here is a dummy example with print, but you can save in a file:

```
import pandas as pd

# df  = pd.read_csv(...)

for k,g in df.groupby('make'):
    print(k)
    for _,r in g.iterrows():
        print(f'  {r["model"]} ({r["yearStart"]-2000:02d}-{r["yearEnd"]-2000:02d})')
```

output:

```
Cadillac
  ATS (13-14)
  XTS (13-15)
Chevrolet
  Malibu (16-20)
  Cruze (16-19)
Hyundai
  Santa Fe (13-18)
  Genesis (15-15)
Mazda
  3 (14-18)
  CX3 (16-18)
  CX5 (12-18)
  SPEED3 (14-14)
lamborghini
  Aventador (16-20)
```

Comment: Did not realize such few lines could be used to implement the solution. Worked beautifully!

Comment: I made some edits to your solution to send the data to a CSV. Can you check my solution and give me an idea how to properly append the data?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking the input from the CSV file and transform it into a data structure that more closely resembles your desired output. In this case a list of dictionaries might be appropriate. If you are unfamiliar with lists and dictionaries, now is a good time to learn about them.

Comment: What DS algos would be best for doing this?

Comment: @boxingaddict There is no standard algorithm for this. You will need to create your own. And what is "DS"?